# What to use instead of `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` in Rust?

Tags: rust, vector, slice, binary-search

### What we have in C++

C++ has two STL functions: [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) and [`std::upper_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound)

`std::lower_bound` finds first position of searched value if it exists, or position of first value greater.

`std::upper_bound` finds first position with greater value than requested.

Together this functions allows user to find half open iterator range which contains all values equal to searched one.

### In Rust

In Rust we have only [`binary_search`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.binary_search) for slices with some extra predicates but it can return any positions where value equal to searched one.

How I can find first value index or `last value index + 1` like in C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily get behaviour of `std::lower_bound` or `std::upper_bound` in Rust using [`binary_search_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.binary_search_by).

So, replacement of `std::lower_bound`:

```rust
use std::cmp::Ordering;

// This have exact same behaviour as C++ std::lower_bound.
let lower_bound = my_sorted_slice
    .binary_search_by(|element| match element.cmp(&searched_value) {
        // Since we try to find position of first element,
        // we treat all equal values as greater to move left.
        Ordering::Equal => Ordering::Greater,
        ord => ord,
    })
    // Since our comparator never returns `Ordering::Equal`,
    // it would always `Err(idx)`.
    .unwrap_err();

// Another version if we want to have Ok or Err
// like Rust std binary_search.
let (Ok(lower_bound) | Err(lower_bound)) = my_sorted_slice
    .binary_search_by(|element| match element.cmp(&searched_value) {
        Ordering::Equal => Ordering::Greater,
        ord => ord,
    })
    // Check what we found.
    .or_else(|idx| {
        if my_sorted_slice.get(idx) == Some(&searched_value) {
            Ok(idx)
        } else {
            Err(idx)
        }
    });
```

And replacement of `std::upper_bound`:

```rust
use std::cmp::Ordering;

let res: usize = my_sorted_slice
    .binary_search_by(|element| match element.cmp(&searched_value) {
        // Since we try to find position right after searched value,
        // we treat all equal values as less to move right.
        Ordering::Equal => Ordering::Less,
        ord => ord,
    })
    // Since `std::upper_bound` always return position
    // which doesn't point to searched value,
    // we would always get `Err` value from bsearch.
    .unwrap_err();
```

Comment: In C++, std::lower_bound returns the first position less than searched_value, not the first position equal to searched_value, so it's better to use unwrap_err like in the second code.

Comment: @earthmessenger No, it seems that my version is right.

"Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range [first, last) such that element < value (or comp(element, value)) is false, (i.e. that is greater than or equal to value)"

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound

Comment: Yes, you are right. So in the first code, there's no need to check `if my_sorted_slice.get(idx) == Some(&searched_value)`, simply use unwrap_err is OK.

Comment: @earthmessenger Yes, if we want to have same method as in C++, we could do that. However, I thought that I should not move from Rust stdlib version too far because there may be case when caller wants different behaviour depending on if value found or not. I would add entry for exact C++ version to answer.